# XSLT: Copying node data to another node by matching attribute value, Efficiently?

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I coded the XSLT to copy one node data to another by validating the attribute value, I got the desired output but I'm curious to know whether there is an efficient way to do this or if this is the only way to do it. [I'm not an XSLT expert] Can someone help !!!

Please use this link to check instantly.
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBH2/3

**Actual XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<section>
  <p>note 1 : <a href="test1">1</a></p>
  <p>note 2 : <a href="test2">2</a></p>
  <p>note 3 : <a href="test3">3</a></p>
  <note id="test1">hello one</note>
  <note id="test2">hello two</note>
  <note id="test3">hello <i>three</i></note>
  <note id="test4">hello <i>four</i></note>
</section>
```

**Output:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><section>
      <p>note 1 : <a>hello one</a></p>
      <p>note 2 : <a>hello two</a></p>
      <p>note 3 : <a>hello <i>three</i></a></p>
      
      
      
      <note id="test4">hello <i>four</i></note>
    </section>
```

**XSLT Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
<a>
    <xsl:variable name="href" select="@href" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$href = //note/@id">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//note[@id=$href]/node()" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</a>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="note">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@id = //a/@href">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's efficient or not depends on how smart the optimizer in your XSLT processor is. Saxon-EE will do a pretty good job on this, Saxon-HE less so.

If you want to make it efficient on all processors, use keys. Replace an expression like `//note[@id=$href]` with a call on the key() function. Declare the key as

```
<xsl:key name="k" match="note" use="id"/>
```

and then you can get the matching nodes using `key('k', $href)`.

The `xsl:when test="$href = //note/@id"` is redundant, as xsl:copy-of will do nothing if nothing is selected.

In the `note` template, I'm not sure what

```
<xsl:when test="@id = //a/@href">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
</xsl:when>
```

is trying to achieve, because you don't have any elements named "node". If the aim is to avoid processing a note element at this stage if it was already processed from an `a` element, then you could build another index with

```
<xsl:key name="a" match="a" use="1"/>
```

and replace `test="@id = //a/@href"` with `test="key('a', @href)"`